# Metadata OGP.ME Qual o tamanho ideal da imagem para as redes sociais

Tags: html, facebook

Uso o metadatas do [**The Open Graph protocol**](http://ogp.me) para o compartilhamento de redes sociais, em especial o Facebook.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/ogp.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://secure.example.com/ogp.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="400" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
```

Até então não defino o tamanho da imagem `property="og:image:height"`, porem no [Debugger do Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) diz que é recomendado definir o tamanho da imagem. Vocês tem noção qual o tamanho ideal para esta imagem? Há alguma documentação que explique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo as [boas práticas do Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content/), o recomendado é que a imagem tenha no mínimo 1200x630px para ser melhor exibição em dispositivos de alta resolução.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O mínimo recomendado por muito tempo é 200x200, mas já está um pouco ultrapassado para os novos layouts e formas de exibição. Agora o Facebook recomenda 600x315px como mínimo.
O tamanho da imagem usada que designará o  formado do post no mural do usuário e o tamanho do alcance na rede.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outra recomendação importante é manter suas imagens o mais perto possível do aspect reatio 1.91:1 para exibir a imagem completa no Feed de notícias sem qualquer corte.

Answer (score -1):

Segundo https://stackoverflow.com/a/15898292/894546, há uma recomendação próxima ao que eu diria:

- Use uma imagem quadrada (não há consenso, mas usar quadrada irá funcionar)
- Procure usar valores múltiplos de 100, a exemplo de 200x200 (mínimo), 300x300 e 400x400 (todos em px)
- Evite tamanhos muito pequenos (100x100) ou muito grandes