# Adicionar imagem em link compartilhado no Facebook

Tags: facebook

ao tentar compartilhar um link do meu blog no Facebook, o Facebook consegue pegar o texto do artigo, porém ele não carrega as imagens para colocar em miniatura.

Alguém teria ideia do que devo fazer.
A url é: www.sesmt.org

Comment: O link abaixo vai ser muuito útil, comigo era a mesma coisa até que procurei no youtube problema do genero.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mg_2Od9xbVM

Answer (score 3):

Para ter certeza de que o Facebook irá pegar a imagem você precisa usar as [og:tags](http://ogp.me/).

As tags básicas que você precisa inserir em seu site:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
```

É interessante você usar imagens na proporção 1.91:1. O tamanho ideal de imagem é 1200x630px, mas qualquer tamanho acima de 600x315px seguindo a proporção está de bom tamanho.

Vale dar uma lida nas [Boas Práticas de Compartilhamento](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content/) do Facebook ou [nesta outra dúvida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6026/2554) que respondi aqui mesmo no Stackoverflow

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Todas as propriedades metas devem ser adicionadas ou apenas a da Imagem? e o Content tem que ser um link da imagem na URL ou pode ser um link do interior do arquivo? o meu não funcionou bem, mas apareceu imagens do meu site, mas não a que eu quero como "padrão"

Comment: @FabioSouza de preferência adicionar todos os dados, mas se você adicionar só o og:image irá funcionar. E precisa ser a URL da imagem igual está no exemplo acima. Se você não adicionar nada ele irá buscar qualquer imagem do seu site para mostrar. 
Teste os dados no Debugger do Facebook https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Answer (score 0):

Quando eu tentei comparilhar o link do seu site, apareceu uma imagem. Mas caso você não goste da imagem você, pode upar uma imagem clicando em "Adicionar fotos/vídeo", só que com isso você perde a miniatura que o facebook coloca, ou seja, vai ficar o link e a imagem de sua escolha.

Comment: Poderia testar com este link, http://sesmt.org/Blog/Artigo/71 e ve se funciona.

Comment: Com este link realmente não aparece a imagem. Eu dei uma pesquisada sobre o assunto, e parece que como seu site não tem uma imagem fora do Head o facebook não trás. Da uma olhada nesse http://www.gerenciandoblog.com.br/2013/12/facebook-nao-publica-imagem.html, talvez você entenda um pouco melhor.